# Python - BeautifulSoup, get tag within a tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

**How would I got about getting a tag within a tag?**

Out of the td tag here:

```
<td scope="row"><a href="/Archives/edgar/data/1085621/000108562117000004/actuacorp12312016.htm">actuacorp12312016.htm</a></td>
```

I want the value of the href tag within it, primarily the htm link:

```
<a href="/Archives/edgar/data/1085621/000108562117000004/actuacorp12312016.htm">actuacorp12312016.htm</a>
```

I have tags like these:

```
<tr>
<td scope="row">1</td>
<td scope="row">10-K</td>
<td scope="row"><a href="/Archives/edgar/data/1085621/000108562117000004/actuacorp12312016.htm">actuacorp12312016.htm</a></td>
<td scope="row">10-K</td>
<td scope="row">2724989</td>
</tr>
<tr class="blueRow">
<td scope="row">2</td>
<td scope="row">EXHIBIT 21.1</td>
<td scope="row"><a href="/Archives/edgar/data/1085621/000108562117000004/exhibit211q42016.htm">exhibit211q42016.htm</a></td>
<td scope="row">EX-21.1</td>
<td scope="row">21455</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td scope="row">3</td>
<td scope="row">EXHIBIT 23.1</td>
<td scope="row"><a href="/Archives/edgar/data/1085621/000108562117000004/exhibit231q42016.htm">exhibit231q42016.htm</a></td>
<td scope="row">EX-23.1</td>
<td scope="row">4354</td>
</tr>
```

**Code to see all the tags:**

```
base_url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1085621/000108562117000004/" \
               "0001085621-17-000004-index.htm"
    response = requests.get(base_url)
    base_data = response.content
    base_soup = BeautifulSoup(base_data, "html.parser")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `find_all` to first get all `td` tags, and then search for anchors within those tags:

```
links = []
for tag in base_soup.find_all('td', {'scope' : 'row'}):
    for anchor in tag.find_all('a'):
        links.append(anchor['href'])

print(links)
```

Output:

```
['/Archives/edgar/data/1085621/000108562117000004/actuacorp12312016.htm',
 '/Archives/edgar/data/1085621/000108562117000004/exhibit211q42016.htm',
...
 '/Archives/edgar/data/1085621/000108562117000004/acta-20161231_lab.xml',
 '/Archives/edgar/data/1085621/000108562117000004/acta-20161231_pre.xml']
```

You can write a little filter to remove those non-htm links if you want:

```
filtered_links = list(filter(lambda x: x.endswith('.htm'), links))
```

---

To get just the first link, here's a slightly different version that's suited to your use case.

```
link = None
for tag in base_soup.find_all('td', {'scope' : 'row'}):
    children = tag.findChildren()
    if len(children) > 0:
        try:
            link = children[0]['href']
            break
        except:
            continue

print(link)
```

This prints out `'/Archives/edgar/data/1085621/000108562117000004/acta-20161231_pre.xml'`.

Comment: this is a really good solution, thank you. Is there anyway to do it without looping twice? Is there any way to reduce to only one for loop. For example something like base_soup.find_all('td', {'scope' : 'row' {a}}).

Comment: I Just want the first htm, '/Archives/edgar/data/1085621/000108562117000004/actuacorp12312016.htm'

Comment: @Theo Edited my answer with a solution that assumes that the code will be applied to this particular use case only.

Comment: @Theo, Glad to help. :)